# ansible Using loop in array

Tags: ansible

I have multiple array in vars files and I must create multiple path
each **client** must have **prod** and **preprod** path
Can you  help me to set multiple loop in multiple array ?
for "**client**" loop it's working but i don't know hos to set the second loop array "**dev**"

**vars.yml**

```
client:
  - a
  - b

env:
  - prod
  - preprod
```

**main.yml:**

```
- name: This command will enable secret with specified path
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: vault secrets enable "{{enable_version2}}" -path="{{item}}_{{projet}}_{{service}}_{{env}}_{{read}}"  "{{secrets_type }}"
  with_items: "{{client}}"
  loop:    "{{client}}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    client:
      - a
      - b

    env:
      - prod
      - preprod

    project: toto

    service: pipo

    read: bingo

  tasks:
    - name: create my path
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }}_{{ project }}_{{ service }}_{{ item.1 }}_{{ read }}"
      loop: "{{ client | product(env) | list }}"
```

Gives:

```
TASK [create my path] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['a', 'prod']) => {
    "msg": "a_toto_pipo_prod_bingo"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['a', 'preprod']) => {
    "msg": "a_toto_pipo_preprod_bingo"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['b', 'prod']) => {
    "msg": "b_toto_pipo_prod_bingo"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['b', 'preprod']) => {
    "msg": "b_toto_pipo_preprod_bingo"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thks for repply, please can you tell me what is "product" ? I had an issue `TASK [acl-policies : This command will enable secret with specified path] ************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <itertools.product object at 0x7febd5fb9eb0>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}'`

Comment: You are using ansible < 2.9. I fixed my answer so it works in all cases.

Comment: Sorry my bad, ti's working perfectly thx a lot